# As a Bladesinger, can I get the arcane keyword on my basic attacks?

Tags: dnd-4e, optimization, wizard

I'm starting a Bladesinger character. Is there any way to add the arcane keyword to a weapon so that I may use the White Lotus feats with my basic attacks?

Answer (score 6):

#### Probably not.

First, an important caveat: there are **no** weapons that provide power source keywords (martial, divine, arcane, psionic, primal, shadow). There are magic weapons that provide damage type keywords (cold, fire, psychic, etc.), but that's about it.

There isn't any way to directly add the arcane keyword to your basic attacks. What you *can* do is get an at-will power that has the arcane keyword and that can be used as a basic attack. Unfortunately, while there are 3 main ways of doing that, none of them are particularly compatible with Bladesinger.

**Option One: Be a Human *and* the Right Class**
The original human racial feature (as opposed to the version Essentials humans get) allows you to choose an additional at-will power from your class (not your subclass). If you took this option you could choose any of the at-will powers available to any of the different wizard sub-classes (arcanist, sha'ir, mage, or witch). While this could be quite helpful to you in general, I don't believe any of those are melee powers that count as basic attacks (there may not even be any melee powers at all).

**Option Two: Be a Paragon-Tier Half-Elf**
The original half-elf racial feature lets you choose an at-will power from any *other* class and use it once per encounter. At level 11 you can then take a feat, Versatile Master, that then allows you to use that power at will. Notably, this allows you to take the one power that has the arcane keyword *and* counts as a melee basic attack: Eldritch Strike, from the warlock class. Unfortunately, that power depends on either Con or Cha, and is thus a poor choice for a Bladesinger (who depends on Int & Dex).

**Option Three: Be a Hybrid**
The hybrid rules let you essentially cram together two different classes to make a single class with 40% of class A and 40% of class B. This includes choosing a single at-will power for each class. You could hybrid your class with warlock to gain access to Eldritch Strike... except that no hybrid rules were ever published for Bladesinger to my knowledge, so it's impossible to hybrid Bladesinger with anything. On top of that, the hybrid rules are fairly underpowered; the vast majority of hybrid characters end up being strictly worse than a single-class character of either of the classes they combined.

As you can see, options 1 and 3 simply don't work for you, and option 2 would require a **serious** expenditure of resources, probably to the extent of making your character useless at a number of other things.

Comment: Thanx...I kinda figured it wasnt possible but thought I would ask the Gurus...

Comment: +1 for the analysis, but I have to say hybrids are not underpowered, you just have to put in the time to build something powerful.

Comment: @András Any class can be powerful with enough time put in. Most 4e classes allow you to just pick whatever sounds cool as a beginner and still be decent; a hybrid character built that way will be a disaster of uselessness almost every time.

Comment: @ObliviousSage, sure, a hybrid takes more system mastery, but I have seen single classed characters crippled too, starting with Vampire. Every character can be useless if built by a cluless beginner. In my experience DnD4 has the biggest difference between optimized and vanilla characters. This is not the fault of the hybrid rules.

Comment: @András I advise people not to make hybrid characters because it's **hard** to make a good hybrid character, not because it's impossible. A player who isn't *deeply* knowledgeable about the system and the options available to them will find it *vastly* easier to make a non-hybrid character of almost any class (Vampire being one of the notable exceptions) that is useful and fun to play.

Comment: If you put it this way, I completely agree

Answer (score 1):

There is another way. If you can get a Wizard at will that is a melee attack (for example, Beast Switch), then the War Wizard of Cormyr Paragon Path allows you to turn that power into a basic attack. The main way of doing this would be by being a human and getting an extra at will, but the group that I am in allows the retraining of power granted by class features IF they have a level (such as Bladesinger's Magic Missile), so your mileage may vary.